# Divisibility - Math Olympiad: $x|(y^2+m)$ and $y|(x^2+m) $

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, contest-math, divisibility, vieta-jumping

Show that for any positive integer $m$, there is an infinite number of pairs of integers $(x,y)$ satisfying the conditions:

i) $\gcd(x,y)=1 $;

ii) $y \mid x^2+m$;

iii) $x \mid y^2+m$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I lead off by settling the case $m=1$ by applying a technique from an [old answer by Bill Dubuque](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/151641/11619). Only posting this, because I think this has useful, generalizable ideas (but won't take us the distance).

We observe that $(x,y)=(5,2)$ is a solution. In our case $m=1$ we can painlessly conclude that $\gcd(x,m)=\gcd(y,m)=1$. Therefore also $\gcd(x,x^2+m)=\gcd(y,y^2+m)=1$. Therefore the conditions ii)- iii) can be combined to read (keeping condition i)
$$
xy\mid(x^2+1)(y^2+1),
$$
which is equivalent to the requirement
$$
xy\mid x^2+y^2+1.
$$
Given that the single solution $(x,y)=(5,2)$ satisfies the equation
$$
3xy=x^2+y^2+1 \qquad(*)
$$
we are lead to the conclusion that if equation $(*)$ has an infinite number of integer solutions (necessarily coprime), then that settles the claim in the case $m=1$.

Here's the key idea. If $(x,y)$ is a solution of $(*)$, then $(3x-y,x)$ is another. This follows immediately from the observation that for a fixed $x$ the two solutions for $y$ of the quadratic equation sum up to $3x$ (=the negative of the coefficient of the linear term). Using this recursively allows us to generate an infinite number of solutions:
$$
(5,2)\mapsto (13,5)\mapsto (34,13)\mapsto (89,34)\mapsto\cdots
$$

I leave it as an exercise for the reader to show that the numbers in this sequence also appear in the Fibonacci sequence.

To settle the general case we need a mechanism for finding a single solution $(x,y)$ such that both $x$ and $y$ are coprime to $m$. The above machinery most likely then spews out an infinite family of solutions.

Edit: $(x,y)=(1,1)$ should work as the initial solution as per suggestion by Ivan Loh! LOL :-) :D

Comment: So, just to prove that $x^2+y^2+m=dxy$ has infinite comprime solutions, for any $d$... How to do this?

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen $(x,y)=(1,1)$ works...

Comment: This method is also known as [Vieta Jumping](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta_jumping) In this case, we are not looking for a contradiction. Rather, we descend to the base case, then reverse the descent to get all solutions. So in fact you have found all positive integer solutions, assuming you start with $(1,1)$.

Comment: @leticiamat If you read the history of Vieta jumping at the link I provided above, this method was introduced to Olympiad mathematics via IMO 1988 Q6. It has since become a standard technique for solving such Olympiad number theory questions, so this is probably how you are meant to solve it.

Comment: @Ivan: Thanks for the link. I would suggest that the techniques was useful already at IMO1981 (Georgetown), when the equation $(m^2-mn-n^2)^2=1$ was studied. Then the sequence of solutions was formed by pairs of consecutive Fibonacci numbers. Don't remember the number of the question, but "I was there!"

Comment: @Ivan: Thanks for the initial solution :-). I was under the influence of my Friday night Talisker, so I had to wait till dawn to figure out that part :-)

Comment: @leticiamat: It is enough to prove that $x^2+y^2+m=dxy$ has infinitely many solutions for some $d$. One value of $d$ is enough. I used $d=3$ above, but given a single solution $(x,y)$ to the original problem, you can then just find the correct value for $d$.

Comment: @IvanLoh Symmetry / descent on conics is *much* older than a  IMO 1988 problem / "Vieta jumping" - see my answer linked above by Jyrki (and the answer linked there) for further discussion.

Answer (score 4):

We will also add the condition (4) that $ \gcd(xy , m) = 1$ (as pointed out by ThomasAndrews)

Observe that $ (x, y) = (m+1, (m+1)^2 + m) $ is a solution to the conditions.
Condition 1 is easy to verify.
Condition 2 is trivial.
Condition 3 follows easily. [You could also show that the polynomial $(m+1)$ is a factor of the polynomial $[ (m+1)^2 + m ] ^2 + m$ by substituting $m=-1$ to obtain $[ (-1 + 1)^2 + 1]^2 -1 = 0$ and applying the Remainder Factor Theorem.]
Condition 4 is trivial.
Note: For $m=1$, we get $(x, y) = (2, 5)$.

We now proceed by Vieta's Root Jumping (as Jyrki suggested). Given any solution $(x, y)$, we know that $$xy \mid (x^2 + m)(y^2 + m) \Leftrightarrow xy \mid mx^2 + my^2 + m^2 \Leftrightarrow xy \mid x^2 + y^2 + m$$

Hence, there exists a $D$ such that $Dxy = x^2 + y^2 + m$.

Claim: $(y, Dx-y)$ is a another solution. You can either check this through algebraic manipulation, or realize that $Dx-y$ is the other integer root to the above equation (when viewed as a quadratic in $y$). Remember to check all the conditions.

As Ivan suggested, to show that we have distinct solutions, we will show that $x < y \Rightarrow y < Dy-x$, and thus the Veita jumping gives us a strictly increasing sequence. From the product of roots, we get that $(Dx-y) \times x = y^2 + m \geq y^2$. Hence, $x< y \Rightarrow Dy-x \geq \frac {y^2}{x} > \frac {y^2}{y} = y $.

Comment: (+1) but can't you just start with $(1,1)$? Take $x \leq y$ so since the product of roots is $y^2+m \geq x^2+1$ the other root is bigger.

Comment: Of course you can, and you can get to $(1, 1)$ by 'backwards' Vieta jumping. I actually started off with $(1, 1)$ and got $(1, m+1)$ and then $(m+1, m^2+3m+1)$.

Comment: there's one step you assume $(xy,m)=1$. It's true, but don't you have to prove that it is true that $(Dx-y,m)=1$?  Specifically, when you have $xy|(x^2+m)(y^2+m)$ and deduce that $xy|(x^2+y^2+m)$ you are using that $(xy,m)=1$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Agreed. Will edit.

Comment: Also, isn't $Dx-y = \frac{x^2+m}{y}$? If so, how is $(Dx-y)\times x = y^2 +m$? Should that be $(Dx-y)\times y = x^2 + m$?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Fixed. Thanks