# Fibonacci numbers, sum of squares and divisibility

Tags: elementary-number-theory, fibonacci-numbers

Let $(F_n)$ be the Fibonacci sequence (i.e. $F_{n+2} = F_{n+1}+F_n$ with $F_{-1}=1$ and $F_0=0$).

Consider $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}_{\ge 1}$ with $a \le b$, and $D=1+a^2+b^2$, such that $a$ and $b$ divide $D$.

**Question**: Must the ordered pair $(a,b)$ be equal to $(F_{2n-1},F_{2n+1})$ for some $n \ge 0$?

*Remark*: It was checked (by SageMath) for $b<10^5$.

Note that $F_{2n\pm1}$ divides $1+ F_{2n-1}^2 + F_{2n+1}^2$ thanks to the following identity:

*Proposition*: $1+ F_{2n-1}^2 + F_{2n+1}^2 = 3F_{2n-1}F_{2n+1}$.
*proof*: Apply Cassini's identity (below) with $2n$, then  $F_{2n-1}F_{2n+1} = 1 + F_{2n}^2$. Now by definition, $F_{2n} = F_{2n+1} - F_{2n-1}$. Then
$$ F_{2n-1}F_{2n+1} =  1 + (F_{2n+1} - F_{2n-1})^2 = 1 + F_{2n+1}^2 - 2F_{2n+1}F_{2n-1} + F_{2n-1}^2.$$
The result follows. $\square$

*Cassini's identity*: $F_{n-1}F_{n+1} = (-1)^n + F_n^2$.
*proof*: $F_{n-1}F_{n+1} - F_n^2 = \det \left(\begin{matrix} F_{n+1} & F_n \\ F_n & F_{n-1} \end{matrix} \right) = \det \left[\left(\begin{matrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{matrix} \right)^n \right] = \left[\det \left(\begin{matrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{matrix} \right) \right]^n = (-1)^n$. $\square$

Comment: What is your question ? Didn't you prove your claim ?

Comment: Just to clarify: $(a,b)$ is an ordered pair, not the greatest common divisor of $a$ and $b$? Because $\gcd(a,b)=1$

Comment: @Peter Seems to me OP proved only one implication and is asking for the other (any pair $(a,b)$ is of this form)

Comment: @Mastrem: Yes $(a,b)$ is an ordered pair.

Comment: If $(a,b)=(F_{2n-1},F_{2n+1})$, then $b-a=F_{2n}$ and $b-2a=F_{2n-2}$ and $3a-b=a-(b-2a)=F_{2n-3}$, so the first step could be to prove that $(3a-b,a)$ is also such a pair?

Comment: No idea whether this helps , but a positive integer $N$ is a fibonacci number with odd index if and only if $5N^2-4$ is a perfect square.

Comment: See also the answers to the [closely related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/151549/242).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. This uses [Vieta Jumping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta_jumping).  Note first that your $\gcd(a,b) = 1,$   so that $ab| a^2 + b^2 + 1.$     Then $a^2 + b^2 + 1 = 3ab.$  Furthermore, the only Ground Solution, [in the sense of Hurwitz 1907](http://zakuski.utsa.edu/%7Ejagy/Hurwitz_A_1907.pdf), is $(1,1).$   Every solution derives as a finite number of jumps from $1,1.$  That all solutions are   Fibonacci numbers, two indices apart, may be proved by induction.

My way of dealing with this is closer to Hurwitz, and consists in looking at the hyperbola branch $x^2 - kxy + y^2 = -1 \; \; \; $ ($x,y>0$) and the location of any GrundLosung,  which lie between lines $ y = \frac{k}{2} x$  and $ y = \frac{2}{k} x,$  showing by inequalities that there are no such points when $k \geq 4.$  Indeed, the entire arc on which fundamental solutions lies within $0 \leq x \leq 2, 0 \leq y \leq 2. \; $  The endpoints are $(x_1, y_1)$ and $(y_1, x_1)$ with $x_1 = \frac{2}{\sqrt{k^2-4}}$ and $$  y_1 = \frac{k}{\sqrt{k^2 - 4}} = \sqrt{1 + \frac{4}{k-2}}  - \frac{2}{\sqrt{k^2-4}}$$
which is between $1$ and $2 \; . \; \;$
Furthermore, the arc does not pass through $(1,1)$ when $k \geq 4.$

[image]

[image]

Comment: Compare to your [prior answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2940983/242).